# Minimum value of Function

Tags: calculus

I have a function, $f(x) = \sec x + \csc x$ on the interval $x \in (0, \pi/2)$.

The derivative of it is, $f'(x) = \csc^2(x) \sec^2(x) \left(\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x\right)$

Of course, when I tried to solve for $f'(x) = 0$, I realize that $f'(x)=0$ does not exist.

However, the question insists that the there is a minimum. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't mean to give you too much of the answer, but Wolfram Alpha is a really powerful tool when you need more insight about these kinds of problems: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+sec+x+%2B+csc+x It appears your derivative is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: Derivative is: $tan(x) sec(x)-cot(x) csc(x)$, $x = \pi/4$

Comment: I expanded from tan(x)sec(x)−cot(x)csc(x) to (sin x)/(cos^2 x) + (cos x)/(sin^2 x). I am sorry for not formatting properly.

Comment: You lost a $-$ sign

Comment: (sin x)/(cos^2 x) - (cos x)/(sin^2 x) => (sin^3x-cos^3x)/(cos^2 x)(sin^2 x) => (sec^2)(csc^2 x)(sin^3x-cos^3x) Am I wrong with my expansion?

Comment: I see that the negative sign that I missed messed me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should have $$\begin{align}f'(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}\\ &= \frac1{\cos^2x\sin^2x}\bigl(\sin^3x-\cos^3x\bigr)\\ &= \frac1{\cos^2x\sin^2x}(\sin x-\cos x)\bigl(\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x\bigr)\\ &= \frac1{\cos^2x\sin^2x}(\sin x-\cos x)\left(1+\frac12\sin 2x\right).\end{align}$$ The fraction and the right-most factor at the end *can't* be zero for any real $x$. Hence, $f'(x)=0$ if and only if $\sin x=\cos x$. Where does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is $0$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$  as the derivative goes from $-$ to $+$ you really have a minimum.

The correct derivative is 
$$-\cot(x) \csc(x) + \sec(x) \tan(x)$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No roots of $f'(x)$ implies there is no *local* extrema. But on a closed interval, the minimum could also occur at a boundary point...

Comment: That would be true.  But in this case there is a zero of $f'(x)$ in the interval, and $f(x) \to +\infty$ as you approach the boundary points.